# Error con solicitud POST

Tags: javascript, post, fetch

Tengo un archivo .json donde almaceno varios datos y estoy tratando de implementar una funcionalidad que a traves de un form se agreguen otros objetos a ese JSON con las mismas propiedades. Pense en hacer una solicitud de tipo POST pero al hacer el envio del formulario me salta el error "POST * **archivo .json** * net::ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Si sirve de algo este es el codigo de la funcion que tengo. Es para agregar un objeto sobre artistas, generos, etc

```
function addArtist() {
    let name = document.getElementById("artistName").value;
    let picture = document.getElementById("artistPicture").value;
    let info = document.getElementById("artistInfo").value;
    let genres = document.getElementById("artistGenres").value;
    let date = document.getElementById("artistDate").value;
    let country = document.getElementById("artistCountry").value;
      
    let newArtist = {
      "name": name,
      "picture": picture ? picture : "https://i.ibb.co/xfWLG7g/vector-sign-of-people-icon.jpg",
      "info": info,
      "genres": genres,
      "date": date ? date : "Sin información",
      "country": country,
      "fans": 0
    };
    
    let urlJSON = `./json/ArtistsExport.json`;
  
    fetch(urlJSON)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // Agregar el nuevo artista a los datos existentes
        let artists = data.artists || [];
        artists.push(newArtist);
        
        fetch(urlJSON, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ artists })
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log("Artista agregado exitosamente.");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error al agregar el artista:", error);
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error al obtener los datos del archivo JSON:", error);
      });
  }
```

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro, el método `POST` no está permitido en el servidor al que estás enviando los datos. Soluciones: 1. Permitir el método `POST`, si conviene, y si está a tu alcance; 2. Usar `GET` en vez de `POST`, aquí: `method: "GET"`.

Comment: No puedes editar un archivo de esa manera, piensa en los agujeros de seguridad que ocasionaría si se pudiera, Debes tener un programa en el servidor que acepte el POST y edite tu archivo JSON